# Why doesn't Yusuke's body need any nutrition during his coma?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

When Yusuke's soul left his body, and his body is still alive, why didn't his Mother and Keiko feed the body using a feeding tube or something. It really bugs me. If there are spoilers I am fine with that (maybe...).

Comment: I assume this is between episodes 4 and 5 after Yusuke saved Keiko from the fire? Otherwise, could you mention the episodes/chapters to clarify this event?

Comment: Wasn't he dead? Probably wouldn't have done anything. I guess I could be remembering things wrong. Like Aki Tanaka said, some clarification on when rhis happened and an accurate description of the events would help